# Trouble Saving MultiSelect Value

Tags: lightning, slds

I found a code somewhere for multiselect. Here's the component code:

```
<div aura:id="main-div"  class=" slds-picklist slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click" >
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-picklist__labe" style="width:100%"
                aria-haspopup="true" onclick="{!c.handleClick}" onmouseleave="{!c.handleMouseOutButton}" >
            <span class="slds-truncate" title="{!v.infoText}">{!v.infoText}</span>
            <lightning:icon iconName="utility:down" size="xx-small" class="slds-icon" style="position:absolute; right:2px;"/>
        </button>            
        <div class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_fluid slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-10 slds-dropdown_left" onmouseenter="{!c.handleMouseEnter}" onmouseleave="{!c.handleMouseLeave}">
            <ul class="{!'slds-dropdown__list slds-dropdown--length-' + v.dropdownLength}" role="menu">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.options_}" var="option" >
                    <li class="{!'slds-dropdown__item ' + (option.selected ? 'slds-is-selected' : '')}"
                        role="presentation" onclick="{!c.handleSelection}" data-value="{!option.value}" data-selected="{!option.selected}"  >
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" >
                            <span class="slds-truncate">
                                <lightning:icon iconName="utility:check" size="x-small" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small"  />{!option.value}
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </aura:iteration>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, I am having trouble where to put value="{!v.projToDonate}" so I can save it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a multi-select picklist, why not use the standard lightning tag for this:

```
<lightning:dualListbox />
```

Basically you can access to the values selected in your controller with something like this:

```
component.find("mylistbox").get("v.value)
```

Or get the values when the user changes the picklist with:

```
var myValues = event.getParam("value")
```

You can read more about this component in the official [library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:dualListbox/example)

Comment: it would be nice to just use the standard tag for this but I am following a design. I'm new to sf lightning and I'm going through a training. I have to pull it off with that design.

Comment: is the attribute "projToDonate" your list of values that user can select or the selected values?

Comment: No. projToDonate is the attribute that will hold the selected value.

Comment: I find this multi-picklist example: https://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/create-a-custom-salesforce-lightning-multiselect-component. If your component is based on this, the selected values are stored in options_ and has an attribute selected for mark the element. Maybe if you can add the JS in the first post I can edit my answer

Comment: I put the attribute to this tag data-selected="{!v.projToDonate}"  . It created an opportunity record but the the value for the picklist wasn't saved. It is empty.

Comment: Assuming you are using Apex for create the record, you must send the selected values to the Apex, looking at the code you post here, your selected values are stored in "options_" wich is the variable that you have in your iteration. You must use the attribute ".selected" in "options_" for get/modify the selected values.